# delete row with button in custom tableview cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, superview

This is how the structure looks like.

```
--- UIView
   ---- ScrollView
       --- TableView
```

.

```
UIView *topView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -250, 320, 250)];

UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 70, 320, 150) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    tableView.separatorStyle = normal;
    [tableView reloadData];

    [topView addSubview:tableView];

    [self.scrollView addSubview:topView];
```

In the tableview I am working with a custom tableview cell with a button in it. Here is the code for the button in my CellForRowAtIndex

```
[cell.btnDelete addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteAppointment:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Now to get the specific row I do this in my deleteAppointment

```
 UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)button.superview;
    UITableView *tableView = (UITableView *)cell.superview;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    NSLog(@"row: %d",indexPath.row);
```

But it is still giving the following error.

```
-[ExceptionCell indexPathForCell:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x210a2fa0
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You should take a look at my solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

its really Simple, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. just tag your button like

```
cell.button.tag = indexPath.row;
```

remove the value from array or dictionary (thats your dataSource) in button @selector method

```
[array removeObjectAtIndex:button.tag];
```

Now reload the tableView.

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: With that solution you won't have that intuitive animation that the TableView methods DeleteRows gives you !

Comment: you will got the animation, try this. It will first perform the animation then reload the Table for updating the indexes.

Answer (score 0):

The error says you are trying to call `indexPathForCell` on `ExceptionCell`.  `indexPathForCell` is a method on `UITableView`, not `UITableViewCell`.

`cell.superview` is not returning your `UITableView` as you expect.

Comment: Yes I think this is because I put my tableview into my scrollview? is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

What you want when deleting a Row from a TableView is to keep the Intuitive Animation that gives the method DeleteRowsAtIndexPath, I have been around that problem, and finaly found an EASY solution.

As the question asked, we are using a Custom Cell with a Custom UIButton for Deleting the Cell

So, you'll have to use delegate // CallBack.
That following demonstration is for MonoTouch in C#, it's the same in objective C, but methods are named a little bit differently + syntax.

//TableViewController

```
//CALLBACK Methods WHEN DELETING A ROW
public void DeletedItem (MyObject arrayObject, CustomCell cellInstance)
    {
        NSIndexPath[] arrayPath = new NSIndexPath[1] { this.myTableView.IndexPathForCell (cellInstance) };

        this.myArray.RemoveItem (arrayObject);
        this.myTableView.DeleteRows (arrayPath, UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade);
    }


[Export("tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:")]
public virtual UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {

        ...

        cell.FactoryMethodsThatImUsing (myObject.items[indexPath.Row], DeletedItem);

        return cell;

    }
```

//CustomCell

```
public delegate void FOODelegateMethods (MyObject item, CustomCell instance);
public event FOODelegateMethods ItemDeleted;
```

IN MY Factory Method

```
if (!(this.ItemDeleted is Delegate)) {
            this.ItemDeleted += new CustomCell.FOODelegateMethods (ResultCallBack);
        }
```

And then on the DeleteItem Actions

```
partial void DeleteItem (NSObject sender)
    {
        ItemDeleted(arrayObject, this);
    }
```